# change the primary key datatype using code first approach

Tags: c#

How to change the Guid datatype to int datatype of primary key without losing the data using code first approach in .NET?

After fired the `update-database` command throws below error

> Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable.

Comment: It's good insert some code and the complete error message in your question.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for us to help you. Please clearly state your problem (it's hard to understand as it is now), and also show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

GUID cannot be converted to INT without loosing data, but you can add an Id column with a different name.

Possibility 1:

Add a property that you intend to be the primary key, then add-migration.

```
[Key, Required]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Possibility 2:

Make sure the database is perfectly in sync with the model and you have a backup of both.  Add your Id column to your table and set it as the primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Id INT IDENTITY
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY(Id)
```

Update your model to match the changes in the database.

```
[Key, Required]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Delete the _MigrationHistory table from the database and the Migrations folder from your project.  Then enable-migrations.